# WebSphere SPNEGO - Cannot get credential from JAAS Subject for principal

Tags: kerberos, rhel7, websphere, spnego

**PROBLEM**

I get an error trying to enable SPNEGO on the WebSphere application server (WAS ND, single node) 9.0.0.7 . I have succeeded on another server, but for this one I can't find the problem.

I get the following error message:

```
org.ietf.jgss.GSSException, major code: 13, minor code: 0 major string: Invalid credentials minor string: Cannot get credential from JAAS Subject for principal: HTTP/server.aa.bbb.ccc@DDDDDDD.BBB.CCC
```

And from the trace file:

```
javax.security.auth.login.FailedLoginException: Cannot retrieve key from keytab HTTP/server.aa.bbb.ccc@DDDDDDD.BBB.CCC
```

**CONFIGURATION**

1. On the domain controller: `setspn -A HTTP/server.aa.bbb.ccc AD-ACCOUNT-1`
2. `ktpass -out AD-ACCOUNT-1.keytab -princ HTTP/server.aa.bbb.ccc@DDDDDDD.BBB.CCC -mapuser AD-ACCOUNT-1 -crypto AES256-SHA1 -ptype KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL /pass <PASSWORD>`
3. WAS is successfully configured with LDAP connection using the user `AD-ACCOUNT-1`.
4. Keytab stored as `/app/sysx/WebSphere/AppServer/AD-ACCOUNT-1.keytab`
5. `$AdminTask createKrbConfigFile {-krbPath /app/sysx/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/InfoSphere/krb5.conf -realm DDDDDDD.BBB.CCC -kdcHost ddddddd.bbb.ccc -dns ddddddd.bbb.ccc -keytabPath /app/sysx/WebSphere/AppServer/AD-ACCOUNT-1.keytab -encryption aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96}`
6. WAS Admin web console: Global security > SPNEGO web authentication

   7. Kerberos config file: `/app/sysx/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/InfoSphere/krb5.conf`
   8. Keytab: `/app/sysx/WebSphere/AppServer/AD-ACCOUNT-1.keytab`
   9. SPNEGO Filter:
      Host name: `server.aa.bbb.ccc` Kerberos Realm Name: `DDDDDDD.BBB.CCC` Filter Criteria: `request-url^=ibm/iis/igc/services|ibm/iis/igc/secure|ibm/iis/igc-rest;request-url!=noSPNEGO` Trim: `Checked`

I have tried adding all aliases to the `/etc/hosts` based on similar cases I found online, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We followed this guide and that solved the problem:
https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/178395/how-do-i-install-the-unrestricted-policy-files-in/